# Batch file FOR loop using incrementing variable

Tags: batch-file

I've created a batch file that is supposed to assign three attached interface descriptions as a custom variable and afterwards print each of these variables.  Eventually instead of printing I plan on using these variables to configure the interfaces themselves depending on the output, but for now am happy just seeing it assign the variables correctly.

This is how I'm trying to tackle this:

```
set cnt=1
for /f "tokens=12,13*" %%f in ('ipconfig /all^|findstr "Description"') do (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "mess.!cnt!.name=%%h"
  endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
  )
echo mess.0.name
for /l %%t in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
  echo mess.%%t.name
  echo "%mess.0.name%"
  )
pause
```

Though I've gone through almost every conceivable approach using delayedexpansion, I cannot get the batch file to consider mess.cnt.name as a variable that increments with each loop.

Here is a sample of the output:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>test1.bat

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>set cnt=1

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>for /F "tokens=12,13*" %f in('ipconfig /all|findstr "Des
cription"') do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "mess.!cnt!.name=%h"
  endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "mess.!cnt!.name=AirLink USB Ethernet/RNDIS"
  endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "mess.!cnt!.name=LAN9500 USB 2.0 to Ethernet 10/100 Adapter"
  endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "mess.!cnt!.name=Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
  endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>echo mess.0.name
mess.0.name

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>for /L %t in (1 1 4) do (
echo mess.%t.name
echo "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
)
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
echo mess.1.name
echo "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
)
mess.1.name
"Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
echo mess.2.name
 echo "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
)
mess.2.name
"Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
echo mess.3.name
 echo "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
)
mess.3.name
"Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>(
echo mess.4.name
 echo "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
)
mess.4.name
"Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.  I've been beating my head against the wall on this for days.

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set cnt=0
for /f "tokens=1,14*" %%f in ('ipconfig /all^|findstr "Description"^|find /n /v ""') do (
  set "mess%%fname=%%h"
  set /a cnt+=1
  )
echo %mess[1]name%
for /l %%t in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
  CALL echo mess[%%t]name=%%mess[%%t]name%%
  )
SET mess

GOTO :EOF
```

Essentially, the `endlocal` was backing out the setting of `mess.?.name` and the classic cure won't work in a code block.

Equally, the reporting loop (I added another way) you'd need to set `delayedexpansion` to display, or use the syntax I've shown.

Now - it might have worked more easily if you's put exactly one `setlocal/endlocal` around the entire routine and not switched in the code block.

OR- you could have called an internal subroutine to do the `set`ting...

Comment: Thank you Magoo for saving my sanity.  You are my new best friend.  I am wondering however why CALL is required before the echo command.  Still can't find details about this trick.

Comment: @Victor, if this answer helped you, consider to accept it by clicking the checkmark next; this marks your question as solved and shows other users the value of this post...

Comment: `CALL ECHO` is a parsing trick. The argument to `call` is parsed, then executed. The parser replaces `%%t` (a current metavariable) with its current value and other `%%` with `%` (since `%` escapes `%`). COnsequently, what is executed is echo  mess[*valueof%%t*]name=%mess[*valueof%%t*]name%`